# Postgres \copy throws a syntax error at STDOUT when exporting as CSV (v8.0.2)

Tags: postgresql, csv, postgresql-copy

I'm trying to locally download the results of a query as csv on a postgres instance that I have read-only access to (v8.0.2). I've truly read 10 different ways of going about this and have tried implementing them all ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803651/how-to-execute-multiple-queries-using-psql-command-from-bash-shell), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120109/export-postgres-table-to-csv-file-with-headings), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840918/postgresql-export-result-as-csv-from-remote-server), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678664/export-table-to-csv-on-postgres), and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36235/export-remote-postgres-table-to-csv-file-on-local-machine)), but every single time I try to execute the copy command, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
```

Here are five of the roughly 20 permutations I have tried. The foo_bar table is a temporary table that was created as the output of a query.

```
=> \copy "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO '/Users/baz/Downloads/foo_bar.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV

=> \copy "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO '/Users/baz/Downloads/foo_bar.csv' CSV
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO STDOUT CSV

=> \copy "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO '/Users/baz/Downloads/foo_bar.csv' WITH FORMAT "csv"
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  "pg_temp_5.foo_bar" TO STDOUT WITH FORMAT "csv"

=> \copy pg_temp_5.foo_bar TO '/Users/baz/Downloads/foo_bar.csv' With CSV
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  pg_temp_5.foo_bar TO STDOUT With CSV

=> \copy foo_bar TO foo_bar.csv With CSV
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STDOUT"
LINE 1: COPY  foo_bar TO STDOUT With CSV
```

I figure that it isn't a permissions issue, as if it were, I would be thrown a "permission denied" when I try to run the command. I also know that there have been similar issues with the \copy command as documented by postgres [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2BTgmoZebb5-8cnoTdNnCz3%3DAsqrFkzTuoK2FZAEbe3%2BrnF42w@mail.gmail.com), but nothing has been noted specifically with regards to my case. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `\copy` syntax looks fine to me. What's the version of `psql`? 8.0.2 too? If yes I would try a newer version.

Comment: Why you are using an un-supported and discontinued Postgres version?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately, and rather crappily, changing the version is something I have absolutely no immediate control over.

Comment: @michel.milezzi psql version is also 8.0.2, and I sincerely wish I could upgrade, but it isn't something I have control over. I've gotta figure it out using what's at hand.

Comment: @yungblud Well, even you cannot upgrade **server** version, you can still connect to it with a newer version of `psql`.

Comment: @michel.milezzi My bad - I completely misread your question! The client version that I was using is very new, 9.6.3

Comment: I noticed Redshift declares itself as Postgres version 8. Any chance you're actually on Redshift, @yungblud? 
`PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.17498`

Answer (score 1):

I recently got this error.  I realized (as mentioned in
combinatorist's comment) the reason was I was logged into an Amazon redshift db, and not Postgres (psql can be used for both).

My guess is it's not implemented for Redshift.  The workaround I used was Redshift's `unload` statement to unload the data to s3.

```sql
unload ('select * from venue')
to 's3://mybucket/unload/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD_command_examples.html#unload-examples-venue

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to connect to psql from command prompt and execute. Verify user account have access to underlying schema and table in postgresql and also have access to directory tried to generate the data file.

1. psql -h hostname -U username -d databasename -p 5432
2. Provide password when prompted from user account

3.Enter this command: \copy schemaname.tablename TO 'Full Path including filename format' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '' NULL 'NULL';

Refer below as example. First try with table exists in schema.

Example:  \copy test_schema.table1 TO 'E:/in/user/table1.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '' NULL 'NULL';